# Pydantic: Storing attributes that are not part of the model (equivalent of JsonExtensionData in C#)

Tags: python, json, pydantic

I'm using pydantic to load data from a json structure into a `MyModel` instance (see example below). Sometimes the JSON data come with extra keys which are not defined in the class `MyModel`. Anyways I'd like have those data accessible in the deserialized MyModel instance somehow.

Minimal Working Example:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    """
    MyModel has two attributes: foo and bar
    """
    foo: str
    bar: int


my_json = r'{"foo":"foo value", "bar": 42, "baz": "something else"}'
# my_json has the attributes of MyModel + some extra key/value pair(s): key 'baz' in this case
my_model = MyModel.parse_raw(my_json) # I deserialize it
assert hasattr(my_model, "baz") is True # or something similar
```

In this example: **Is there any way to find the `"baz": "something else"` key value pair in the deserialized `my_model` instance?**

I know this behaviour exists in other Frameworks e.g. in C#/.NET as [`JsonExtensionData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonextensiondataattribute?view=net-7.0):

> ... any properties that do not have a matching member are added to that [annotated] dictionary during deserialization and written during serialization.

Is there something similar for pydantic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. That is what the `extra` setting in the [model config](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/model_config/) is for. By default it is set to `ignore`. You can set it to `allow`:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    foo: str
    bar: int

    class Config:
        extra = "allow"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_json = '{"foo":"foo value", "bar": 42, "baz": "something else"}'
    my_model = MyModel.parse_raw(my_json)
    assert hasattr(my_model, "baz")
    print(my_model)  # foo='foo value' bar=42 baz='something else'
```

**PS**: It may be worth mentioning that no static type checker will be able to infer that this particular `MyModel` instance has a `baz` attribute. That means no auto-suggestion for `my_model.baz` from your IDE and so on. But I think that is obvious.